# How to give PowerShell WorkFlow access to previously imported modules

Tags: powershell, workflow

I'm trying to introduce PowerShell workflow into some existing scripts to take advantage of the parallel running capability.

Currently in the WorkFlow I'm having to use:

```
Inline
{
   Import-Module My.Modules
   Execute-MyModulesCustomFunctionFromImportedModules -SomeVariable $Using:SomeVariableValue
}
```

Otherwise I get the error stating it can't find the custom function. There must be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article at http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/11/14/powershell-workflows/ confirms that having to import modules and then use them is just how it works - MS gets around this by creating WF activities for all its common PowerShell commands:

> General workflow design strategy
>
> It’s important to understand that the entire contents of the workflow
>   get translated into WF’s own language, which only understands
>   activities. With the exception of a few commands, Microsoft has
>   provided WF activities that correspond to most of the core PowerShell
>   cmdlets. That means most of PowerShell’s built-in commands—the ones
>   available before any modules have been imported—work fine.
>
> That isn’t the case with add-in modules, though. Further, because each
>   workflow activity executes in a self-contained space, you can’t even
>   use Import-Module by itself in a workflow. You’d basically import a
>   module, but it would then go away by the time you tried to run any of
>   the module’s commands.
>
> The solution is to think of a workflow as a high-level task
>   coordination mechanism. You’re likely to have a number of
>   InlineScript{} blocks within a workflow because the contents of those
>   blocks execute as a single unit, in a single PowerShell session.
>   Within an InlineScript{}, you can import a module and then run its
>   commands. Each InlineScript{} block that you include runs
>   independently, so think of each one as a standalone script file of
>   sorts: Each should perform whatever setup tasks are necessary for it
>   to run successfully.